# Magento 2 system config get frequency full value

Tags: magento2.2.2, system-config

in magento system config xml one can use:

```
<field id="frequency" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
     <label>Frequency</label>
     <source_model>Magento\Cron\Model\Config\Source\Frequency</source_model>
     <backend_model>Magento\Cron\Model\Config\Backend\Sitemap</backend_model>
</field>
```

This will create an html select option:
[image]

As you can see the selected option value is `weekly` on save config magento store as `W` When I retrieve I get `W` but I need full value like `Weekly`

Does magento provide to fetch full value if so how?

Comment: Could you please provide the Source Model code.

Comment: @PritamInfo24  that's it this is all I have the model is the xml `Magento\Cron\Model\Config\Source\Frequency`   But I have mapped with array like: `$frequencyOptions  = ["D"=>"Daily", "W"=>"Weekly", "M"=>"Monthly"];`  Then I get option from `core_config` and retrieve from array : `$frequencyOptions[$frequency]`; Where $frequency  would one of : `D, W, M` .